# DateListPlot in webMathematica doesn't show FrameTicks properly

Tags: plotting, bugs, webmathematica

It seems that DateListPlot when used in webMathematica (3.3.1) show different output than in desktop Mathematica (10.1).

In desktop Mathematica, if you evalutate

```
data = {{{2015, 1}, 10}, {{2015, 2}, 6}, {{2015, 3}, 15}};
DateListPlot[data]
```

will show this picture:

[image: desktop Mathematica output]

in webMathematica instead, when you call this code (html removed for clarity) in .jsp file from your browser

```
<msp:evaluate>
      data = {{{2015, 1}, 10}, {{2015, 2}, 6}, {{2015, 3}, 15}};
      MSPShow[DateListPlot[data]]
</msp:evaluate>
```

it will show the graph without the vertical and horizontal Ticks:

[image: webMathematica .jsp 1st output]

Then I've tried to add   FrameTicks -> True   (and Frame-> False otherwise it doesn't show them)

```
<msp:evaluate>
      data = {{{2015, 1}, 10}, {{2015, 2}, 6}, {{2015, 3}, 15}};
      MSPShow[
         DateListPlot[data
           ,Frame-> False
           ,FrameTicks -> True]]
</msp:evaluate>
```

the output now shows the ticks but in Scientific Notation. No way to display the ticks in date format:

[image: webMathematica .jsp 2nd output]

It appears as a bug for me, because other functions as Plot[] or ListPlot[] produce a regular output. This strange behavior seems to be peculiar to DateListPlot[].

Does anyone has encountered the same problem or found a workaround?

*(I've post this question also in the [Wolfram Community Forum](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/517557?p_p_auth=R2XaEcf9))*

Comment: I am also affected by this but under the Wolfram Script environment instead of webMathematica. I added more info under your Wolfram Community post and also added a "bugs" tag because this has been reproduced by wolfram support [CASE:3450946]

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me under Linux and Windows. 
Make sure you specified the right Kernel and FrontEnd in MSPConfiguration.xml.
I.e., in Windows add this  before `</MSPConfiguration>` in MSPConfiguration.xml

```
<KernelExecutable>
        C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\MathKernel.exe
</KernelExecutable>

<FrontEndExecutable>
        C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.1\Mathematica.exe
</FrontEndExecutable>
```

while under Linux I use:

```
<KernelExecutable>
      /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/Executables/MathKernel
</KernelExecutable>

    <FrontEndExecutable>
          /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/Executables/Mathematica
    </FrontEndExecutable>

     <JLinkNativeLibraryDirectory>
        /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64
      </JLinkNativeLibraryDirectory>

    <FrontEndLaunchFlags>
    -display :1 -nogui -geometry 1920x1050+10+10
    </FrontEndLaunchFlags>
```

Also I use this (on Centos ) in /etc/init.d/tomcat:

```
#!/bin/sh
#chkconfig: 2345 95 20

CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat; export CATALINA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default; export JAVA_HOME
TOMCAT_OWNER=tomcat; export  TOMCAT_OWNER

start() {
  echo -n "Starting Tomcat:  "
  su - $TOMCAT_OWNER -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

}
stop() {
   echo -n "Stopping Tomcat: "
   su - $TOMCAT_OWNER -c $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
}

##

case "$1" in
    start)
      start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    *)
       echo $"Usage: tomcat {start|stop|restart}"
   exit
esac
```

Comment: Thank you Rolf, but on my Linux server the MSPConfiguration.xml has already a similar configuration (it differ only in the resolution of -geometry).
The problem affect only DateListPlot so I don't think that can be a configuration problem. Do you use webMMA 3.3.1/Tomcat 8 /Java 1.8 on your Linux?

Comment: webMathematica 3.3.1 , Tomcat 8.0.23, Oracle Java 8.0.45

Comment: Same configuration: CentOS, Tomcat 8.023, JVM 1.8.0_45-b14, webMMA 3.3.1, MMA 10.1

Comment: Rolf, please, can you tell me which version of webMathematica is displayed in the 'Manager App' page of Tomcat? I ask this because I've downloaded and installed v.3.3.1 (as it appear on the Wolfram download page), but in Tomcat it shows as 3.3.0. Maybe this is the glitch.

Comment: Indeed, it says 3.3.0. But this is because in web.xml it says so. Why don't you just contact Wolfram support?